# teamviewerd is running but Teamviewe.exe is not

Tags: 12.04, teamviewer

Teamviewer suddenly doesn't work anymore. I have teamviewer 11 installed on my ubuntu 12.04. Teamviewer was installed by downloading teamviewer_11.0.67687_i386.deb and double clinking it (as suggested). No error occured during installation. I tried removng it and reinstalling but no difference. The process teamviewerd is running but Teamviewer.exe not.
When I type 'teamviewer' in command line i get:

```
$teamviewer
Init...
XRandRWait: No value set. Using default.
XRandRWait: Started by user.
Checking setup...
Launching TeamViewer ...
Launching TeamViewer GUI ...
```

but nothing happens...

when i open

```
 $cat /opt/teamviewer/logfiles/TeamViewer11_Logfile.log
 Start:              2016/12/22 15:50:06.791 (UTC+1:00)
 Version:            11.0.67687 
 ID:                 0
Loglevel:           Info (100)
License:            0
Server:             master15.teamviewer.com
IC:                 1935685710
CPU:                Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz
CPU extensions:     h9
OS:                 Lx Ubuntu precise 12 (32-bit)
IP:                 157.193.116.33,10.0.3.1
MID:                1935685710_b0a92d17_26c01986cfce510a
MIDv:               0
Proxy-Settings:     Type=0 IP= User=

2016/12/22 15:50:06.792  1672 4149057280 S           RemoteSettingsMDRelationshipWatchDog: DEVICE ISN'T A MANAGED DEVICE
2016/12/22 15:50:06.792  1672 4034898752 S   RemoteSettingsStore: Cleanup all policies.2016/12/22 15:50:06.792  1672 4149057280 S   RemoteSettingsStoreListener: Establish connection.
2016/12/22 15:50:06.792  1672 4034898752 S   RemoteSettingsStore::LoadLastReceivedPolicies : Storage Entry Remote_Settings_TVClientSetting_Policy empty
2016/12/22 15:50:06.792  1672 4149057280 S   Using IPC-Port 5939
2016/12/22 15:50:06.792  1672 4034898752 S   RemoteSettingsMDRelationshipWatchDog: DEVICE ISN'T A MANAGED DEVICE
2016/12/22 15:50:06.793  1672 4149057280 S   Updated sessions: [ 1000000  L root ]  
2016/12/22 15:50:06.793  1672 4149057280 S   UpdateOnlineState newOnlineValue 0
2016/12/22 15:50:06.793  1672 4149057280 S   UpdateOnlineState newOnlineValue 0
2016/12/22 15:50:06.793  1672 4149057280 S   UpdateResponseLinux: success 1 updated 0 rev 0
2016/12/22 15:50:06.794  1672 4068469568 S!  No method for suspend/resume monitoring found
2016/12/22 15:50:07.033  1672 4097616704 S   XSocket observer: adding XSession: 0
2016/12/22 15:50:07.033  1672 4076862272 S   Updated sessions: [ 0     ]  [ 1000000  L root ]  
2016/12/22 15:50:07.033  1672 4076862272 S   UpdateOnlineState newOnlineValue 0
2016/12/22 15:50:07.284  1672 4107270976 S   ConsoleKitSessionInfo: New session ConsoleKitSessionInfo [id=/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session1 user=lightdm state=undef active=1 reliable=0 infoId=0] [path=/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session1 created=2016-12-22T14:50:07.085541Z display= remotehost= seat=/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Seat1 type=LoginWindow x11display=:0 x11tty=/dev/tty7 loginid=4294967295 uid=104 idle=0 active=1 local=1]
 2016/12/22 15:50:07.284  1672 4076862272 S   XSession: 0 [SysSession 0 [type=1 tty=7 pseudotty=0 info=1 id=/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session1 user=lightdm state=greeter active=1 reliable=1]]
2016/12/22 15:50:07.284  1672 4076862272 S   Updated sessions: [ 0 CL lightdm ]  [ 1000000  L root ]  
2016/12/22 15:50:07.284  1672 4076862272 S   UpdateOnlineState newOnlineValue 0
 2016/12/22 15:50:15.855  1672 4107270976 S   XSession[0]: Retrieved XAuth from commandline
 2016/12/22 15:50:15.855  1672 4076862272 S   XSession: 0 [SysSession 0 [type=1 tty=7 pseudotty=0 info=0 id= user= state=undef active=1 reliable=1]]
 2016/12/22 15:50:15.855  1672 4076862272 S   Updated sessions: [ 0 C   ]  [ 1000000  L root ]  
2016/12/22 15:50:15.855  1672 4076862272 S   UpdateOnlineState newOnlineValue 0
2016/12/22 15:50:16.159  1672 4107270976 S   ConsoleKitSessionInfo: New session ConsoleKitSessionInfo [id=/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2 user=frederik state=undef active=1 reliable=0 infoId=1] [path=/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2 created=2016-12-22T14:50:15.662622Z display= remotehost= seat=/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Seat1 type= x11display=:0 x11tty=/dev/tty7 loginid=4294967295 uid=1001 idle=0 active=1 local=1]
2016/12/22 15:50:16.159  1672 4076862272 S   XSession: 0 [SysSession 0 [type=1 tty=7 pseudotty=0 info=1 id=/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2 user=frederik state=user active=1 reliable=1]]
 2016/12/22 15:50:16.160  1672 4076862272 S   Updated sessions: [ 0 C  frederik ]  [ 1000000  L root ]  
2016/12/22 15:50:16.160  1672 4076862272 S   UpdateOnlineState newOnlineValue 0
2016/12/22 15:50:16.795  1672 4068469568 S   Session login for session 0
2016/12/22 15:50:16.795  1672 4068469568 S           CTerminalServer::RepeatedlyCheckForUserLogin() Don't start GUI for session 0
```

Does someone have an idea how to fix this?

kind regards

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include some more details: How did you install teamviewer? Did you get error messages?

Comment: i downloaded teamviewer from the teamviewer website: teamviewer_11.0.67687_i386.deb

Comment: ...and ran it by double clicking.() as suggested by the manual